# Java create Map of single value using stream collector groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

I know the `groupingBy` return a `Map<K,List<V>>`. But If I know that each key has a unique value, how do I get a Map whose value is `V` instead of `List<V>`?

For example:

```
Map<String, Transaction> transactions =
transactions.stream().collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getID));
```

where ID is unique.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

using Collectors.toMap:

```
Map<String, Transaction> transactions = transactions.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Transaction::getID, Function.identity()));
```